# onclick not replicated in JavaScript

Tags: php, list, dynamic, menu, onclick

I have got a couple of issues I need resolved with JavaScript.

The first is a problem with my JavaScript onclick method not being replicated when I duplicate a dynamic menu. This image might below help you better understand my issue:

[image]

The first problem is that the method that I've written for the original form in the image above - the first table row - has a working function that executes smoothly when the checkbox is ticked - the replicated dynamic menu doesn't have that function working when its ticked. Basically, there are two checkboxes with different values - "yes" and "no" - when the "no" checkbox is ticked, the "Yes" checkbox  becomes disabled and unclickable - and vice versa - however this option is not working for me when I duplicate the form as a dynamic form.

The onclick option doesn't work for any of the checkboxes. The onclick method seems to be working for the "+" button when replicated though for some reason.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
       <body>
        <form>

          <div id="container1">
<table border="1" id="education" name="education[]" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="name" size="3"> <font size="3">Name of Institution</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="institution" size="3"><font size="3">Type of Institution </font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="instaddress" size="3"> <font size="3">Address</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label><font size="3">From</font></label></td>
<td valign="top"><label><font size="3">To </font> </label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="graduate" size="3">  Did You <br> Graduate?</label></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="averages" size="3">  Average <br>Grade</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" id="name" name="name[]" maxlength="30" size="20"></td>
<td valign="top"><select name="institution[]" id="institution">
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['institution'])) { echo $_POST['institution']; } ?>>Institution</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['institution']==$_GET['id3'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[institution]>$row1a[institution]</option>");
}
?>
</select></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" id="instaddress" name="instaddress[]"  maxlength="50" size="40"></td>
<td valign="top">

<select name="monthto[]" id="monthto">
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['month'])) { echo $_POST['month']; } ?>>Select Month</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['month']==$_GET['id4'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
}
?>
</select>

<select name="toyear[]" id="toyear">
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['year'])) { echo $_POST['year']; } ?>>Select Year</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY id desc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['year']==$_GET['id5'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
}
?>
</select>

</td>


<td valign="top"> 
<select name="monthto1[]" id="monthto1" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['month'])) { echo $_POST['month']; } ?>>Select Month</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['month']==$_GET['id6'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[month]>$row1a[month]</option>");
}
?>
</select>
<select name="toyear1[]" id="toyear1" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option <?php if(isset($_POST['year'])) { echo $_POST['year']; } ?>>Select Year</option>
<?php
$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY id desc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['year']==$_GET['id7'])
echo("<option selected value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
else
echo("<option value=$row1a[year]>$row1a[year]</option>");
}
?>
</select>


</td>
<td valign="top">Yes<input type="checkbox" id="graduate" name="graduate[]" onclick="cleardata2()" value="yes"> No
<input type="checkbox" id="graduate1" name="graduate[]" onclick="cleardata3()" value="no"> </td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" id="averages" name="averages[]"  maxlength="100" size="3"></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="#" id="Add" name="Add" onclick="addFields1()">+</a>
<a href="#" type="hidden" id="Remove" name="Remove" onclick="rFields1(this)"></a>
</td>


</table>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cleardata2()
{
if (document.getElementById('graduate').checked == true)
  {

  document.getElementById('graduate1').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }
  else {
//  document.getElementById("cleaning").onclick = null;

  document.getElementById('graduate1').removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}

function cleardata3()
{
if (document.getElementById('graduate1').checked == true)
  {

  document.getElementById('graduate').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }
  else {
//  document.getElementById("cleaning").onclick = null;

  document.getElementById('graduate').removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}


</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function rFields1(elm){
        var tr = elm.parentNode.parentNode;
        tr.remove();

        }
        function addFields1(){

            var container = document.getElementById("container1");
            var table = document.createElement("table");

            table.border=1; 
            table.cellspacing=0;     
            table.id ="education";
            table.name = "education[]";     
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.valign = "top";

            var name = document.createElement("input");
            name.type = "text";
            name.id = "name";
            name.name = "name[]";
            name.size = 20;
            name.maxlenth = 30;
            container.appendChild(name);
            td.appendChild(name);
            tr.appendChild(td);

            var td1 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.valign = "top";

var slct = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
  slct.id = "institution";
  slct.name = "institution[]";
//some php code that is generating js code
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[institution]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[institution]';\r\n");
        echo("slct.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>

slct.value='<?php echo $_GET['id2']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
container.appendChild(slct);//? how do I fix this up
        //      select1.appendChild(option);
td1.appendChild(slct);
tr.appendChild(td1);

var td2 = document.createElement("td");
td2.valign = "top";
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.id = "instaddress";
input.name = "instaddress[]";
input.value = '<?php echo $_GET['id3']; ?>';
input.size = 40;
input.maxlenth = 50;
container.appendChild(input);

container.appendChild(input);//? how do I fix this up
        //      select1.appendChild(option);
td2.appendChild(input);
    tr.appendChild(td2);



var td3 = document.createElement("td");
td3.valign = "top";

var slct1 = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
 slct1.id = "monthto";
slct1.name = "monthto[]"; 
//some php code that is generating js code
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id asc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[month]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[month]';\r\n");
        echo("slct1.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>

slct1.value='<?php echo $_GET['id4']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
container.appendChild(slct1);//? how do I fix this up
td3.appendChild(slct1);
tr.appendChild(td3);

var td4 = document.createElement("td");
td4.valign = "top";

var slct2 = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
slct2.id = "toyear";
slct2.name = "toyear[]"; 
//some php code that is generating js code
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY id desc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[year]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[year]';\r\n");
        echo("slct2.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>

slct2.value='<?php echo $_GET['id5']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
container.appendChild(slct2);//? how do I fix this up
td4.appendChild(slct2);
tr.appendChild(td4);

var td5 = document.createElement("td");
td5.valign = "top";

var slct3 = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
 slct3.id = "monthto1";
slct3.name = "monthto1[]"; 
//some php code that is generating js code
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM month ORDER BY id asc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[month]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[month]';\r\n");
        echo("slct3.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>

slct3.value='<?php echo $_GET['id6']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
container.appendChild(slct3);//? how do I fix this up
td5.appendChild(slct3);
tr.appendChild(td5);

var td6 = document.createElement("td");
td6.valign = "top";

var slct4 = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
slct4.id = "toyear1";
slct4.name = "toyear1[]"; 

//some php code that is generating js code
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM year ORDER BY id desc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[year]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[year]';\r\n");
        echo("slct4.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>

slct4.value='<?php echo $_GET['id7']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
container.appendChild(slct4);//? how do I fix this up
td6.appendChild(slct4);
tr.appendChild(td6);

var td7 = document.createElement("td");
td7.valign = "top";
                        td7.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Yes"));        // checkbox buttons whether someone graduated or not          



                        var grad = document.createElement("input");
                        grad.type = "checkbox";
                        grad.id = "graduate";
                        grad.name = "graduate[]";
                        grad.value = "yes"; //yes value for checkbox button





                        var grad1 = document.createElement("input");
                        grad1.type = "checkbox";
                        grad1.id = "graduate";
                        grad.name = "graduate[]";
                        grad.value = "no"; //no value for checkbox button

                        container.appendChild(grad);
                        td7.appendChild(grad);
                        td7.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" No "));


                        container.appendChild(grad1);
                        td7.appendChild(grad1);
                        tr.appendChild(td7);

                        var td8 = document.createElement("td");
                        td8.valign = "top";

                        var averages = document.createElement("input");
                        averages.type = "text";
                        averages.id = "averages";
                        averages.name = "averages[]";
                        averages.size = 3;
                        averages.maxlenth = 100;
                        container.appendChild(averages);

                        td8.appendChild(averages);

                        tr.appendChild(td8);


                //        var addInstitution = document.getElementById("Add");
                 //       var removeInstitution = document.getElementById("Remove");
                 //  container.removeChild(addInstitution);
            var td12 = document.createElement("td");
            td12.valign = "top";

            var add1 = document.getElementById("Add");

            //create and insert input/text

            //create and insert button
            add1 = document.createElement("a");
            add1.id="Add"
            add1.name="Add"
            add1.href="#";
            add1.text="+";
            add1.onclick=function(){addFields1();};
            td12.appendChild(add1);

            tr.appendChild(td12);    
            var td13 = document.createElement("td");
            td13.valign = "top";        
            var remove1 = document.getElementById("Remove");        
            remove1 = document.createElement("a");
            remove1.id="Remove";
            remove1.name="Remove";
            remove1.href="#";
            remove1.text="-";
            remove1.onclick=function(){
            rFields1(this);};
            td13.appendChild(remove1);

            tr.appendChild(td13);  

            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));


            table.appendChild(tr);  
            container.appendChild(table);   


        }

    </script>
```

The other problem is also similar. It's for the same form as well but rather a different task.

As you can see, the original form (not the replicated one which was dynamically created) has a dropdown list - but the drop down list starts with the header "Institution" - on the other hand - the dynamically created/replicated form doesn't allow me to have a proper header for the drop down list which I retrieved from the server.

The code that I used - to retrieve and display the data as can be seen in the dynamically replicated form is the following (based in PHP but within a snippet of JavaScript code):

```
   var slct = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
  slct.id = "institution";
  slct.name = "institution[]";
//some php code that is generating js code
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();
    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[institution]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[institution]';\r\n");
        echo("slct.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>

slct.value='<?php echo $_GET['id2']; ?>';                       //container.add(option);
container.appendChild(slct);//? how do I fix this up
        //      select1.appendChild(option);
td1.appendChild(slct);
tr.appendChild(td1);
```

I tried too many ways to fix this issue up, but I couldn't get the top header in the drop down list to say "Institution" or any other label/heading instead of directly printing the first type of institution retrieved from the database (in this case "college") before the user clicks on the arrow pointed down to retrieve his/her options in the form to submit data.

What should I have to write in PHP to solve the main header issue in the drop down menu?

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes instead of radio buttons for yes/no?

Comment: You never add `grad.onclick` or `grad1.onclick`. Why would you expect anything to run when you click on them?

Comment: checkboxes are easier for me - and i'm using arrays so it complicates it when using radio buttons....where should i insert the grad.onclick and grad1.onclick lines?

Comment: i tried it barma...its still not coming

Comment: The `onclick` in the HTML only works for the elements created with HTML. If you create new elements with Javascript, they need their own `onclick` properties.

Comment: IDs also have to be unique. You're using the same ID `graduate` for all the checkboxes you're adding dynamically.

Comment: i changed the ids and the ids are the same in the original HTML form and it works...so the dynamic ones should work as well - the "+" and "-"
 buttons work perfectly...why is this one not coming?

Answer (score 1):

You're giving all your checkboxes the same ID. That won't work, because IDs have to be unique. `getElementById('graduate')` will just return the first checkbox, not the checkbox on the same row as the one you're clicking on. You need to rewrite `cleardata2` and `cleardata3` so they take the current checkbox as a parameter, and find the corresponding checkbox of the other type:

```
function cleardata2(self) {
    var other_cb = self.nextSibling.nextSibling; // Skip over "yes" text node to next checkbox
    disable_other(self, other_cb);
}
function cleardata3(self) {
    var other_cb = self.previousSibling.previousSibling; // Skip over "no" text node to previous checkbox
    disable_other(self, other_cb);
}
function disable_other(self, other) {
    if (self.checked) {
        other.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        other.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}
```

Change your HTML to:

```
<td valign="top">Yes<input type="checkbox" id="graduate" name="graduate[]" onclick="cleardata2(this)" value="yes"> No
```

And change the code that creates the new checkboxes to:

```
var grad = document.createElement("input");
grad.type = "checkbox";
grad.name = "graduate[]";
grad.value = "yes"; //yes value for checkbox button
grad.addEventListener("click", function() { cleardata2(this); });

var grad1 = document.createElement("input");
grad1.type = "checkbox";
grad1.name = "graduate[]";
grad1.value = "no"; //no value for checkbox button
grad1.addEventListener("click", function() { cleardata3(this); });
```

Comment: yippy...it works!!! can u help me out with the second part of the question now please? thnx a mill!

Answer (score 0):

ok finally I guess I found your mistake, You have a typo while creating a dynamic graduate input type.

```
             var grad = document.createElement("input");
                        grad.type = "checkbox";
                        grad.id = "graduate";
                        grad.name = "graduate[]";
                        grad.value = "yes"; //yes value for checkbox button

            var grad1 = document.createElement("input");
                grad1.type = "checkbox";
                grad1.id = "graduate1"; //in your code you have graduate
                grad1.name = "graduate[]";
                grad1.value = "no"; //no value for checkbox button
```

if it still doesn't work try adding onclick property to your dynamic JS:

```
     var grad = document.createElement("input");
                grad.type = "checkbox";
                grad.id = "graduate";
                grad.name = "graduate[]";
                grad.value = "yes"; //yes value for checkbox button
                grad.onclick = cleardata3;

     var grad1 = document.createElement("input");
         grad1.type = "checkbox";
         grad1.id = "graduate1"; //in your code you have graduate
         grad1.name = "graduate[]";
         grad1.value = "no"; //no value for checkbox button
         grad1.onclick = cleardata3;
```

For the second part of the question try:

```
<?php
    $sql1a = "SELECT * FROM institution ORDER BY institution asc";
    $smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
    $smt1a -> execute();

    while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

        echo("var opt=document.createElement(\"option\");\r\n");
        echo("opt.value='$row1a[institution]';\r\n");
        echo("opt.text ='$row1a[institution]';\r\n");
        if($row1a['institution']==$_GET['id3']){
            echo("opt.setAttribute(\"selected\", true);\r\n");
        }
        echo("slct.appendChild(opt);");
    }
?>
```